How to disable a QPushButton until function is completed?
I need to disable the button until the function is completed.
   self.button_apply.clicked.connect(self.apply_clicked)

 def apply_clicked(self):
        """Events when accept button is pushed""" 
        self.button_apply.setEnabled(False)
                
        self.text_edit.append("button clicked")   
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.create_credentials_folder(self.samba_path_credentials))        
        self.button_apply.setEnabled(True)

It is not disabling the button.
The process should be: I click on button -> it gets disabled until all processes finished, but it is not disabling.

A QTimer doesn't block the function, so the button is immediately re-enabled again. If you want the function to wait until self.create_credentials_folder() is finished, you should remove the timer and just call the function. Or else, make  self.create_credentials_folder() emit a signal when it's finished and connect the button enable to that.

Or just re-enable the button at the end of the create_credentials_folder slot. (Presumably, the slot blocks GUI updates, which might delay the initial disabling of the button if called directly).
